# d3 Reactive Chart with Meteor

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript, meteor, dimple.js

I am creating a simple reactive mortgage in meteor.  You can see it here:
http://mortgage.meteor.com/

My issue is the graph.  It should update as the sliders change, which it does, but I think I need to remove the "old/previous" chart data.

Here is my code:

```
Template.visualization.rendered = () ->
    svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart", 500, 500)
    Deps.autorun () ->
        data = [
          {
            Lifetime: "Payments"
            Dollars: Session.get("totalPayments")
          }
          {
            Lifetime: "Interest"
            Dollars: Session.get("lifetimeInterest")
          }
        ]
        chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data)
        chart.addCategoryAxis "x", "Lifetime"
        chart.addMeasureAxis "y", "Dollars"
        chart.addSeries null, dimple.plot.bar
        chart.draw()
```

Comment: For me in chrome it is updating the chart when I change the sliders, but it is not clearing the previous chart. Maybe add `d3.select("#chart").remove()` within the Deps.autorun callback? *Edit* `d3.select("#chart").selectAll("g").remove()` would be worth a try too.

Comment: d3.select("#chart").selectAll("g").remove() worked!  Thanks!